# Heroku Push Error Assets Precompiling Port Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having trouble pushing to heroku.

Here is my heroku log http://pastebin.com/M7q7qJ3x

The error occurred around here

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

and here is my database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: restaurant_development
  pool: 5
  username: judyngai
  password:
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: restaurant_test
  pool: 5
  username: judyngai
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: restaurant_production
  pool: 5
  username: judyngai
  password:
  host: localhost
```

should I change the host to "127.0.0.1" and add in a port ? 
This is odd. I don't understand this.

and here is another error

```
Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
```

I did not touch the js,css files at all.

Should I be "compiling assets" locally before I push? I am not quite familiar with assets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config in `application.rb` or `production.rb` add

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile

Add this

```
gem 'sass', '3.2.13'
```

its work for me.